# Add int to a range object

Tags: c#

How to add a `int` to a `string` Range so that "[A2:B10]" becomes "[A3:B10]"?
RowColRange is in the code a string with a Range.
The code works as expected but i want the first row 2 to 3.

The Input Sheet and RowColRange is defined by user input.
[image]

The Problem is E69 starts from E70 in the xls file.

[image]

[image]

```
if (Execute)
{
    OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection();
    con.ConnectionString = ("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;"
        + "Data Source = " + PathOpen + ";"
        + "Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES\"");
    OleDbCommand com = new OleDbCommand("select * from [" + Sheet + "$" + RowColRange + "]", con);
    System.Data.DataSet dSet = new System.Data.DataSet();
    OleDbDataAdapter dAd = new OleDbDataAdapter(com);
    dAd.Fill(dSet);

    DataTree<string> myTree = new DataTree<string>();
    int colCount = dSet.Tables[0].Columns.Count;
    for (int c = 0; c <= colCount - 1; c++)
    {
        foreach (DataRow row in dSet.Tables[0].Rows)
            myTree.Add(("" + row[c]), new GH_Path(c));
    }
    Table = myTree;

}
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add more code, where do you define `Sheet` and `RowcolRange` ?

Comment: What exactly is the problem with changing `RowColRange` to a different value?

Answer (score 0):

so here is a solution (i am sure not a good one) but i split the string and convert the nessesary part into string and join everything together before it goes to the commandtext.

```
  Regex re = new Regex(@"([a-zA-Z]+)(\d+)([:])([a-zA-Z]+)(\d+)");
  Match result = re.Match(RowColRange);
  int Num = Int32.Parse(result.Groups[2].Value) - 1;
  string newRange = ((result.Groups[1].Value + Num + result.Groups[3].Value + result.Groups[4].Value + result.Groups[5].Value).ToString());
```